# Lines Appearing In iFrame in Chrome while scrolling up

Tags: google-chrome, iframe

So, I've got a CSS drop down menu with links, when you click on a link, the page loads in an iframe placed below the css menu. I have two problems.

1) In Google Chrome, there are think gray lines that appear in the iFrame when scrolling up, and there are more and they are more condensed when you actually drag the scroll bar up.

2) Some of the links are to PDF files, when those load into the iFrame, they display over the top of pieces of the CSS menu.

Any ideas? I've found a few articles with similar issues for the thin lines, but none of the solutions I've seen seem to be working.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>AHCS - eLearning Portal - Caregiver Welcome</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="portal.css" />

</head>

<body>
  <div id="cgframeinner">
    <div id="reflibcontainer">
    <div id="reflibhead">
        <h2>Reference Library</h2>
    </div>
  <div id="reflibnav">
    <span style="display:block;"><ul id="css3menu1" class="topmenu">
        <li class="toproot"><a href="#" style="height:16px;line-height:16px;"><span>COPD</span></a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://copdfoundation.org/COPDYou/COPDTrainingVideos.aspx" target="frame2">COPD Training Videos</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://copdfoundation.org/" target="frame2">COPD Foundation</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://copdfoundation.org/portals/0/files/pdfs/4-fact-sheet-LMBB.pdf" target="frame2">COPD Fact Sheet</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://copdfoundation.org/portals/0/files/pdfs/BreathingBetterwithCOPD.pdf" target="frame2">Breathing Better With COPD</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://copdfoundation.org/COPDYou/Glossary.aspx" target="frame2">COPD Glossary of Terms</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://copdfoundation.org/Portals/0/Files/pdfs/What%20is%20COPD1.pdf" target="frame2">What is COPD?</a></li>

        </ul></li>
        <li class="toproot"><a href="#" style="height:16px;line-height:16px;"><span>CHF</span></a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://www.heart.org/HEARTORG/Conditions/CongenitalHeartDefects/TheImpactofCongenitalHeartDefects/Congestive-Heart-Failure_UCM_307111_Article.jsp" target="frame2">American Heart Association</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.webmd.com/heart-disease/guide-heart-failure" target="frame2">WebMD CHF Guide</a></li>
        </ul></li>
        <li class="topmenu"><a href="#" style="height:16px;line-height:16px;">Pneumonia</a></li>
        <li class="topmenu"><a href="#" style="height:16px;line-height:16px;">Fall Risk</a></li>
        </ul></span>
    </div>
    <iframe src="" width="500px" height="350px" name="frame2"></iframe>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```